# batch file for loop with spaces in dir name

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

How do I modify this:

```
for /f %%a IN ('dir /b /s build\release\*.dll') do echo "%%a"
```

to work when the path contains spaces?

For example, if this is run from

```
c:\my folder with spaces
```

it will echo:

```
c:\my
```

Thanks

Comment: Try not to use parameter extensions letters for variables, if you later need to add them the code will be hard to read and prone to errors. They are f d p n x s a t z. The easiest and safest way is to use upper-case letters (i.e. %%a and %%A are different variables).

Answer (score 110, accepted):

You need to use:

`for /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /b /s build\release\*.dll') do echo "%%a"`

This overrides the default delimiters which are TAB and SPACE

Answer (score 37):

I got around this by prepending "type" and putting double quotes surrounding the path in the IN clause

```
FOR /F %%A IN ('type "c:\A Path With Spaces\A File.txt"') DO (
    ECHO %%A
)
```

[This article](http://www.celticproductions.net/articles/12/batch+files/file+path+and+name+with+spaces+in+batch+file+for+loop.html) gave me the idea to use "type" in the IN clause.

Comment: Quotes are the only option when using /D instead of /F (only /F takes delims).

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want to deal with "quotes" you can use the "s" switch in %~dpnx[]...
this will output the short filenames that are easy to work with.

from the Command line...

```
for /f "delims=" %f IN ('dir /b /s "C:\Program Files\*.dll"') do echo %~sdpnxf
```

inside a .CMD/.BAT file you need to "escape" the [%] e.g., double-up [%%]

```
for /f "delims=" %%f IN ('dir /b /s "C:\Program Files\*.dll"') do echo %%~sdpnxf
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is there's a wildcard in the string that gets interpreted as a filename.  You also need double quotes for a string with spaces.  I'm not sure if there's a way to escape the wildcard.

```
for %a IN ("dir /b /s build\release\.dll") do echo %a
```

```
"dir /b /s build\release\.dll"
```