# VB6 script to build multiple vbp

Tags: build, vb6

I am using this script to build multiple vbp in a folder "TEST"

```
    FOR  /r "C:\TEST\" %%f IN (*.vbp) DO "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\VB98\vb6.exe" /m /out C:\TEST\log.txt %%f
```

However, if the vbp project folder has spaces between the folder name, e.g. `C:\TEST\vbp project1`, the build script will be failed to build that vbp project.

How can I amend the script to support a vbp project folder with spaces within the folder name?

Comment: Try `"%%f"` for the last param

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5553040/batch-file-for-loop-with-spaces-in-dir-name