# Open multiple files from cmd dir output with notepad++

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, pipe, io-redirection

What I want to do:
Use a dir command to find a bunch of text files, then open them all in Notepad++. Preferably in a single command without creating extra files.
Normally, you can just say

```
notepad++ zed.txt ./ted/zed.txt ./red/zed.txt
```

But I need to open many files in a complex directory structure.

I feel like I should be able to do something like this:

```
dir /s/a/b "zed.txt" | notepad++
```

This does give me the output I want (recursively finds files and spits out just the filenames), but each on its own line and Notepad++ doesn't open them, it just opens and asks to create the file "notepad++" - which is empty.

Even using an extra file (undesirable, but not preferable) does not work:

```
c:\Users\tonip\Desktop\some_dir>dir /s/a/b "cmakelists.txt" > np.txt && notepad < np.txt
```

or

```
dir /s/a/b "cmakelists.txt" > np.txt
notepad++ < np.txt
```

N.B. Notepad++ directory is on my path.

Obviously, my re-direction skills are not good. Help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for /f "delims=" %a IN ('dir /a-d /b /s *.csv') do call notepad++ "%a"
```

This seems to work for me. Of course you will need to modify your 'dir /b' criteria to whatever files you are trying to match.

This command loops through all the files output by dir (only csv files in my case) and opens them with notepad++. Be sure to include the /b after your dir command to only output filenames without all of the other information.

Comment: This will fail on file names with spaces.  You also need to add the /S option to recursively search.

Comment: Is there a fix to the command to work with spaces in filenames that you know off the top of your head?

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Squashman, just tested it with spaces in the file name and it worked for me.

Comment: @dxxAnthonyxxb Can you tell me what `-d` is doing?
Also, if anyone can explain why my own code **doesn't** work, that would be appreciated.

Comment: @dxxAnthonyxxb , that works like a charm.
I will definitely give this answer credit unless someone can tweak my attempt and get it to work.
Would definitely note any explanation for why mine failed. Thanks!

Comment: Note that you can just use `for /r %a in (*.csv)` instead. Your way is overly convoluted and likely to break with spaces (it already has in its previous iteration) or non-ASCII characters. `for` is perfectly capable of iterating over a list of files without the need to call `dir`.

Comment: This method run notepad++ one time _for each file_ (several executions). The original description execute notepad++ just one time _with several files_.

Comment: @Joey Thanks for the input. That seems to add something to the discussion, but when I ran it, the results were not good. It attempted to created a bunch of new files (not something I wanted). I used the full command: `for /r %a in (*.csv) do call notepad++ "%a"` While @TheRealKernel 's solution doesn't do it the way I wanted, it definitely gets the result I want, so I think I'll stick with it. I guess I didn't say it explicitly, but I wanted it to open them all as a single command.

Answer (score 5):

This works for me in the command-line:

```
(for /F "delims=" %a in ('dir /s/a/b "zed.txt") do call set "list=%list% "%a"") & call notepad++ %list%
```

Just be sure that `list` variable does not exist before execute this line.

Answer (score 1):

Redirecting the file names with path without double quotes from command **DIR** to *Notepad++* does not work because *Notepad++* is a GUI application which does not read in file names from standard input stream **STDIN** line by line.

*Notepad++* expects a space separated list of (double quoted) file name(s) as command line parameter(s) whereby the double quotes around a file name with no path, a relative path or an absolute path are not always needed depending on characters in file name and file path.

My first suggestion is:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "Files="
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir zed.txt /A-D /B /S 2^>nul') do set "Files=!Files! "%%I""
if not "!Files!" == "" notepad++.exe%Files%
endlocal
```

This batch code concatenates the found files to a long parameter list starting always with a space and starts *Notepad++* with that list.

The problem with this simple code is that the length of the parameter list could exceed the maximum length for an environment variable string if there are really many files with file name `zed.txt`.

A simple solution would be to limit the number of files per *Notepad++* run for example to 25.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "Files="
set "FileCount=0"
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir zed.txt /A-D /B /S 2^>nul') do (
    set "Files=!Files! "%%I""
    set /A FileCount+=1
    if !FileCount! == 25 (
        notepad++.exe!Files!
        set "Files="
        set "FileCount=0"
    )
)
if not %FileCount% == 0 notepad++.exe%Files%
endlocal
```

The best solution would be to check on each loop run the current length of the environment variable before appending next file name. But this would make the batch file slower and usually the file names with path are not so long that 25 files per *Notepad++* execution is really a problem.

Well, theoretical a single file name with path could be already too long for being assigned to an environment variable.

**Note:** If the batch file execution is halted after starting *Notepad++* and this behavior is not wanted, insert left to each `Notepad++.exe` the string `start ""` to start *Notepad++* in a separate process with an empty title string. Don't omit `""` after command **START** before `Notepad++.exe` as otherwise first double quoted string (= first file name with path) would be interpreted as title string.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`
- `start /?`

See also the Microsoft documentation page about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul`. The redirection operator `>` is escaped here with `^` to apply the redirection of **STDERR** to device **NUL** on execution of command **DIR**. This redirection is used to suppress the error message output by command **DIR** if it can't find any `zed.txt` in current directory or any subdirectory.

Comment: Thanks for addressing my original attempt, and the added depth is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this on ubuntu (wsl) also

```
for file in $(find -type f)
do
    notepad++.exe $file
done
```

shorthand would be:

```
for file in $(find -name zed.txt); do notepad++.exe $file;done
```

variations on this would be to exclude certain subfolders. this script will exclude any temporary folders like .git

```
for dir in $(find -maxdepth 1 -type d;egrep -v '^\./\.')
do
    for file in $(find $dir -type f|egrep '(zed|foo)')
    do
        notepad++.exe $file
    done
done
```

or scan for text before opening the file:

```
for file in $(find -type f|egrep '(zed|foo)')
do
    for l in $(cat $file|egrep -i '(foo)')
    do
        notepad++.exe $file
        break
    done
done
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example opening files in notepad++ off a file share matching a pattern. Place this code into a "finder.bat" file and double click on it.

```
for /f "delims=" %%f IN ('dir /b /s "\\server\c$\Program Files (x86)\MyUtility\*.exe.config"') do call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" %%~sdpnxf
```

Idea formulated from https://stackoverflow.com/a/5564349/194872